# How to configure IntelliJ formatting for array declaration?

Tags: intellij-idea

I would like to use the formatter to enforce array declarations to keep the [] with the type and not with the variable. I'm not seeing a formatter option for this though, but I'm not sure if I'm just missing it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is an inspection for this called "C-style array declaration". It has a quick fix to automatically move the brackets to the type.